# Coq syntax highlighting

Tags: packages, code

I'd like to get a decent syntax highlighting for Coq code in LaTex. Does anyone know what package, `.sty` or whatnot is commonly used for this? I tried [minted](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) and got a syntax highlighting that's too generic for Coq:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{coq}
  Module Type types.
    Parameter P PI: Type.
  End types.
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you specify `coq` to minted ? (if so I'll delete my answer) As always your question would be clearer if you had provided a small example document and said what is wrong with the output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I specified Coq w/ `\begin{minted}{coq} ... \end{minted}`. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: yes, so that's probably the best you are going to get unless the coq community have hand written something (about which you would get more on a coq mailing list than here I would think) But if there errors in pygments' coq lexer if you report them there they get fixed and minted will then pick them up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About something hand written: I found [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/594606/filename/lstcoq.sty) but don't think it works w/ minted

Comment: for minted you need to have a style in pygmentize, as that's what it is a latex wrapper for pygments. the one you link to there is a setup for listings package not minted. For most languages minted does a better job of semantically correct highlighting as it's easier to write a lexer in python than tex, but if that listings version meets your needs that's fine...

Comment: I added the minted output.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was originally asked for minted, but let me share a listing configuration file that was apparently first created by [Assia Mahboubi](http://people.rennes.inria.fr/Assia.Mahboubi/) and shared (and tweaked?) by [Nick Giannarakis](https://github.com/nickgian).

The following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{ltblue}{rgb}{0,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{dkviolet}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.5}

% lstlisting coq style (inspired from a file of Assia Mahboubi)
\lstdefinelanguage{Coq}{ 
    % Anything betweeen $ becomes LaTeX math mode
    mathescape=true,
    % Comments may or not include Latex commands
    texcl=false, 
    % Vernacular commands
    morekeywords=[1]{Section, Module, End, Require, Import, Export,
        Variable, Variables, Parameter, Parameters, Axiom, Hypothesis,
        Hypotheses, Notation, Local, Tactic, Reserved, Scope, Open, Close,
        Bind, Delimit, Definition, Let, Ltac, Fixpoint, CoFixpoint, Add,
        Morphism, Relation, Implicit, Arguments, Unset, Contextual,
        Strict, Prenex, Implicits, Inductive, CoInductive, Record,
        Structure, Canonical, Coercion, Context, Class, Global, Instance,
        Program, Infix, Theorem, Lemma, Corollary, Proposition, Fact,
        Remark, Example, Proof, Goal, Save, Qed, Defined, Hint, Resolve,
        Rewrite, View, Search, Show, Print, Printing, All, Eval, Check,
        Projections, inside, outside, Def},
    % Gallina
    morekeywords=[2]{forall, exists, exists2, fun, fix, cofix, struct,
        match, with, end, as, in, return, let, if, is, then, else, for, of,
        nosimpl, when},
    % Sorts
    morekeywords=[3]{Type, Prop, Set, true, false, option},
    % Various tactics, some are std Coq subsumed by ssr, for the manual purpose
    morekeywords=[4]{pose, set, move, case, elim, apply, clear, hnf,
        intro, intros, generalize, rename, pattern, after, destruct,
        induction, using, refine, inversion, injection, rewrite, congr,
        unlock, compute, ring, field, fourier, replace, fold, unfold,
        change, cutrewrite, simpl, have, suff, wlog, suffices, without,
        loss, nat_norm, assert, cut, trivial, revert, bool_congr, nat_congr,
        symmetry, transitivity, auto, split, left, right, autorewrite},
    % Terminators
    morekeywords=[5]{by, done, exact, reflexivity, tauto, romega, omega,
        assumption, solve, contradiction, discriminate},
    % Control
    morekeywords=[6]{do, last, first, try, idtac, repeat},
    % Comments delimiters, we do turn this off for the manual
    morecomment=[s]{(*}{*)},
    % Spaces are not displayed as a special character
    showstringspaces=false,
    % String delimiters
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[d]’,
    % Size of tabulations
    tabsize=3,
    % Enables ASCII chars 128 to 255
    extendedchars=false,
    % Case sensitivity
    sensitive=true,
    % Automatic breaking of long lines
    breaklines=false,
    % Default style fors listings
    basicstyle=\small,
    % Position of captions is bottom
    captionpos=b,
    % flexible columns
    columns=[l]flexible,
    % Style for (listings') identifiers
    identifierstyle={\ttfamily\color{black}},
    % Style for declaration keywords
    keywordstyle=[1]{\ttfamily\color{dkviolet}},
    % Style for gallina keywords
    keywordstyle=[2]{\ttfamily\color{dkgreen}},
    % Style for sorts keywords
    keywordstyle=[3]{\ttfamily\color{ltblue}},
    % Style for tactics keywords
    keywordstyle=[4]{\ttfamily\color{dkblue}},
    % Style for terminators keywords
    keywordstyle=[5]{\ttfamily\color{dkred}},
    %Style for iterators
    %keywordstyle=[6]{\ttfamily\color{dkpink}},
    % Style for strings
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    % Style for comments
    commentstyle={\ttfamily\color{dkgreen}},
    %moredelim=**[is][\ttfamily\color{red}]{/&}{&/},
    literate=
    {\\forall}{{\color{dkgreen}{$\forall\;$}}}1
    {\\exists}{{$\exists\;$}}1
    {<-}{{$\leftarrow\;$}}1
    {=>}{{$\Rightarrow\;$}}1
    {==}{{\code{==}\;}}1
    {==>}{{\code{==>}\;}}1
    %    {:>}{{\code{:>}\;}}1
    {->}{{$\rightarrow\;$}}1
    {<->}{{$\leftrightarrow\;$}}1
    {<==}{{$\leq\;$}}1
    {\#}{{$^\star$}}1 
    {\\o}{{$\circ\;$}}1 
    {\@}{{$\cdot$}}1 
    {\/\\}{{$\wedge\;$}}1
    {\\\/}{{$\vee\;$}}1
    {++}{{\code{++}}}1
    {~}{{$\sim$}}1
    {\@\@}{{$@$}}1
    {\\mapsto}{{$\mapsto\;$}}1
    {\\hline}{{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}}1
    %
}[keywords,comments,strings]

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Coq]
Module Type types.
Parameter P PI: Type.
End types.
\end{lstlisting}

Hello World in Coq, courtesy of http://coq-blog.clarus.me/tutorial-a-hello-world-in-coq.html.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Coq]
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Io.All.
Require Import Io.System.All.
Require Import ListString.All.

Import ListNotations.
Import C.Notations.

(** The classic Hello World program. *)
Definition hello_world (argv : list LString.t) : C.t System.effect unit :=
System.log (LString.s "Hello world!").
\end{lstlisting}

Inductive definition, courtesy of https://coq.inria.fr/a-short-introduction-to-coq.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Coq]
  Inductive even : N -> Prop :=
| even_0 : even 0
| even_S n : odd n -> even (n + 1)
with odd : N -> Prop :=
| odd_S n : even n -> odd (n + 1).
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

gives the (not fully satisfactory, in my opinion) following:

[image]

It seems to me that minted actually does a better job, as the following

```
% !TeX document-id = {34714a8d-170f-4947-a4b9-b8812e4a094a}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{tango}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{coq}
Module Type types.
Parameter P PI: Type.
End types.
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}{coq}
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Io.All.
Require Import Io.System.All.
Require Import ListString.All.

Import ListNotations.
Import C.Notations.

(** The classic Hello World program. *)
Definition hello_world (argv : list LString.t) : C.t System.effect unit :=
System.log (LString.s "Hello world!").
\end{minted}

Inductive definition, courtesy of https://coq.inria.fr/a-short-introduction-to-coq.

\begin{minted}{coq}
Inductive even : N -> Prop :=
| even_0 : even 0
| even_S n : odd n -> even (n + 1)
with odd : N -> Prop :=
| odd_S n : even n -> odd (n + 1).
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: If you want to highlight SSR, you can probably re-use the macros in https://arxiv.org/e-print/1912.06611 developed by Assia Mahboubi as well.

Comment: The above syntax definition hides all tilde `~` characters: `{~}{{\ }}1`. I've replaced the line with `{~}{{$\sim$}}1` to make negation visible again.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten, I've edited my answer.